# Incorrect usage of WITH ROLLUP and DISTINCT issue

Tags: mysql, mamp

I have recently updated to MAMP 5.0, which was probably not the best idea as there has been a few changes more particularly in mysql.

I am trying to run a local version of a team developed site and my environment keeps failing to produce an output for a query that has a DISTINCT and a ROLLUP.

eg.

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.tier, u.dept, l.name
```

...

```
GROUP BY l.name, u.dept WITH ROLLUP;
```

Is there any way to get a query like this to work without having to change the query itself? *This query used to work prior to me upgrading MAMP (earlier version of mysql).*

I have found that a bug was submitted to Oracle https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76229 but it doesn't seem like there is any resolution from what I can tell and maybe this change was by design.

Comment: `GROUP BY l.name, u.dept` will already give you distinct values. Could you explain why you want to use a distinct there (e.g. an result that you do not want, that would get corrected by a "distinct" there), so we might give you an alternative to get the result you need?

Comment: In general, you will never see DISTINCT and GROUP BY in the same query. Indeed, a GROUP BY clause has no place in any query absent of any aggregating functions.